# sqoop-export is failing when I have \N as data

Tags: hive, sqoop

Iam getting below error when I run my sqoop export command.

This is my content to be exported by sqoop command

```
00001|Content|1|Content-article|\N|2015-02-1815:16:04|2015-02-1815:16:04|1      |\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N
00002|Content|1|Content-article|\N|2015-02-1815:16:04|2015-02-1815:16:04|1      |\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N|\N
```

sqoop command

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:1234/db --table table1 --username user1 --password pass1--export-dir /hivetables/table/   --fields-terminated-by '|' --lines-terminated-by '\n'  -- --schema schema
```

> 15/06/09 08:05:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1431442954745_1210_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task
>   logs
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Can't parse input data: '\N'**
>           at duser.__loadFromFields(duser.java:690)
>           at duser.parse(duser.java:558)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
>           at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:202)
>           at duser.__loadFromFields(duser.java:627)

Can you help me resolve it ?

Comment: Can you share the schema of the postgres table?

Comment: Try adding these arguments to the export statement --input-null-string "\\\\N"
--input-null-non-string "\\\\N"

Comment: It worked - @highonprogramming, add this in answer section.

Comment: Glad it worked. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding these arguments to the export statement

```
--input-null-string "\\\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\\\N"
```

From the documentation:

> If --input-null-string is not specified, then the string "null" will
>   be interpreted as null for string-type columns. If
>   --input-null-non-string is not specified, then both the string "null" and the empty string will be interpreted as null for non-string
>   columns.

If you don't add those arguments, it won't be able to understand that the `\N` in your data is actually `null`.

Comment: From a sqoop documentation website, I found:  --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N', but it does not work. I switched to highonprogramming's code, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the order in which columns are being imported. Sqoop doesn't automatically understand the column mapping. Try using `--columns` argument to specify the order the columns appear in. Here's how to use it:

`sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/reports ... --columns col1,col2,col3,...`

See http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_4 for documentation on how to use `--columns`.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the script with --column, but still getting same error.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd ` is the error to look at. I'd ask your question on the sqoop mailing list where they can walk you through the issue.